# C++ cout in method good programming style

Tags: c++, oop, methods

What do you thing, should I use `cout <<` in methods? Or should I return an array? Because I need more then one return `value`.

I have the class `SGetraenkeAutomat`, here is the `.h` file

```
class SGetraenkeAutomat
{
    public:
        // this method
        void DisplayInventory();

        SGetraenkeAutomat();
        SGetraenkeAutomat(int nColaAnzahl, int nSpriteAnzahl, int nFantaAnzahl);
        virtual ~SGetraenkeAutomat();
    private:
        int m_nColaAnzahl;
        int m_nSpriteAnzhal;
        int m_nFantaAnzahl;
};
```

the method `void SGetraenkeAutomat::DisplayInventory()` in `SGetraenkeAutomat.cpp`

```
void SGetraenkeAutomat::DisplayInventory(){
    std::cout << m_nColaAnzahl;
    std::cout << m_nSpriteAnzahl;
    std::cout << m_nFantaAnzahl;
}
```

Is that a good programming style?

-> I dont think so, but maybe someone of you can explain it me.

Comment: usually its better to have something like a toString() method which creates a Stringified Object representation which can then be printed to any stream you like. or also return the struct like the next commenter suggested. depending on what you want to do

Comment: The method is called `Display...`, so I would expect it to use cout or a gui. If it returned the inventory in an array, it would be called `Get...`. What you have is self-consistent

Comment: @KaiIskratsch thanks for the comment. Can you give me a little example?

Comment: the easiest way of such a method would be just using std::stringstream and feeding it with the same output you have in dislpay, and then return the result as std::string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather rename it to `PrintInventory` and provided an optional argument:

```
    void PrintInventory(std::ostream &output = std::cout);
```

This way you can output your inventory to some other stream and at the same time you don't have to specify it each time you want to print to stdout.

```
void SGetraenkeAutomat::PrintInventory(std::ostream &output){
    output << m_nColaAnzahl;
    output << m_nSpriteAnzahl;
    output << m_nFantaAnzahl;
}
```

This way you can do either:

```
automat.PrintInventory(); // prints to stdout
```

or something like

```
automat.PrintInventory(std::cerr); // prints to stderr, for example
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added this function prototype into my `*.h` file. How can I display the inventory now?

Comment: @MyNewName, what do you mean? Just like you did before. Only now you have an option to pass in another argument if you even want to do so.

Answer (score 1):

> Or should I return an array?

No. The class has 3 `private` members, it's better not to expose them outside, which result in tight coupling at most case.

> should I use cout << in methods?

If it statisfies the request, it should be fine.

Comment: Should I make them public then? Because I want to display the inventory.

Comment: @MyNewName It's better to make a public member method for display the inventory, to encapsulate them all inside the class.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, because the method is called `DisplayInventory`, one would not expect it to return anything, but actually show the inventory to the user in some way.  This is in alignment with the [Tell, Don't Ask](https://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) "rule" which says you should tell your objects what to do, not ask them questions about their state.

In a simple application, using `cout` to interact with the user is perfectly acceptable; another option would be to use a GUI to display the information.

You could also look at it this way: to display the inventory to the standard output, you *must* use `cout` *somewhere*.  It is certainly better (in my opinion) to encapsulate it in a class method than exposing all the data with a getter (thus breaking "tell, don't ask") and printing it outside the class.

If you want to get more fancy and get the output customizable, you could create some kind of formatter class and pass it to the display function (Sergey's answer is a variant of this principle).

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your task. If you need to display variables than use some stream to display. If other classes from your program require data from your SGetraenkeAutomat class than you should provide public getters for each private member. For ex:

```
int get_ColaAnzahl()
{
 return  m_nColaAnzahl;
}
```

As I can see in your case will be better to create some base class (lets name it Drink):

```
struct Drink {
int count;
std::string name;
}
```

Then modify your SGetraenkeAutomat class to:

```
class SGetraenkeAutomat
{
    public:
        // this method
        void DisplayInventory() {
           for (auto drink: drinks) {
              std::cout << drink.name << ": " << drink.count << std::endl;
           }
        }

        void addDrink(const Drink& drink) {
          drinks.push_back(drink);
        };
        SGetraenkeAutomat();
        virtual ~SGetraenkeAutomat();
    private:
        std::vector<Drink> drinks;
};
```

I think you understand my idea described above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I like this idea. The struct `Drink`, its a own class (Drink.h & Drink.cpp)? When I want to fill up one specific drink, I have to iterate over the whole vector?

Comment: @MyNewName vector is for example, of course you can use std::map<std::string, int> or std::unordered_map<std::string, int> where key is name and value is count. Or other collection, depending on your task. In case of map you don't need to create struct Drink until your drink's parameters will not grow (at the moment you have only one drink parametr: count), then the value of the map will be you struct that contains all drink parameters. It will looks like this std::map<std::string, Drink>.